# I won't lose in my game Stone, Paper and Scissor

Tags: python, function

I am a beginner in python. Started a week ago.
So I created a basic Stone, paper and scissor game with user input and random guess for computer.
See the program below.

```
import random
random_element = random.randrange(1,4)
computer = random_element
print("Computer have choosen their, Now it's your turn.")
player = int(input("Plyer's Turn: Enter (1) to choose Stone, (2) for Paper, and (3) for Scissor:\n"))
if player == 1:
    player = 'Stone'
if player == 2:
    player = 'Paper'
if player == 3:
    player = 'Scissor'
if computer == 1:
    computer = 'Stone'
if computer == 2:
    computer = 'Paper'
if computer == 3:
    computer = 'Scissor'
def game(computer,player):
   bool = 1
    if computer == player:
        bool = None
    elif  computer == 1:
        if player == 2:
           bool = True
        if player == 3:
        bool = False
    elif computer == 2:
        if player == 3:
            bool = True
        if player == 1:
            bool = False
    elif computer == 3:
        if player == 1:
            bool =  True  
        if player == 2:
            bool = False      
    return bool

if player == 1:
    player = 'Stone'
if player == 2:
    player = 'Paper'
if player == 3:
    player = 'Scissor'    


answer = game(computer,player)

if answer == True:
    print(f"Computer chosen: {computer} \nand You chosen: {player} \nSo, You Won the Game.")

if answer == False:
    print(f"Computer chosen: {computer}\nand You chosen: {player}\nSo, You loose the Game.")

if answer == None:    
    print(f"Computer was chosen: {computer}\nand you choose: {player}\nIt is a Tie..")
```

But after some time to try this game. I realise that I won every time except Tie. I don't know why.
I check my program too many time and checks winning and losing statement too many times. But I won't found my error.

Please help me.
This is my first game.

If someone have good experience in python then answer me proper, simple but short method (without importing too many modules).

Comment: FYI you shouldn't name stuff `bool`, or any other built-in name in Python. `bool` is a data type, but you've overwritten (or more accurately, "shadowed") the name, so you can't access that data type by name anymore.

Comment: Hi, please check [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). If you'd step through your code _with a debugger_ and looked at all the things happening live, you'd have an easier time spotting the problem. Hint: `computer == 1` will never be true because `computer` is something like `'Stone'` at that point. Also, there is a `bool = False` incorrectly indented...

Comment: Just making an error in programing now it seems like far better then winning genuinly.

Comment: Agreed that you need to learn how to debug your programs. It's something that any programmer needs to learn on day 1, alongside actual coding, since otherwise you'll be forever crippled as a developer. There's a free, easy-to-use debugger in PyCharm (which has a free version), which is really good - see [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/debugging-your-first-python-application.html) for a tutorial on how it works. Not using a debugger is like designing an airplane and only testing if it works by trying to build it.

Comment: Use an array `['Scissor', 'Stone', 'Paper']` and check use modular arithmetic to determine the winner after selecting two numbers between 0 and 2.

Comment: Additionally to naming the variable like  a datatype (`bool`), the name doesn't even describe well the property of the variable as it can take three values: `True`, `False` and `None`...

Comment: Also there is https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html which is _really_ helpful. After I plugged in your code, it first complained about the indention errors, and once fixed, I was able to step through everything happening, and it's visible here that the values are strings and not numbers: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0LPe.png

Comment: @CherryDT  I fix that issue with bool by replacing it. but still winning game.

Comment: @user17086391 Did you debug the code yet? Look at the guide and the visualizer tool I linked... also check out PyCharm as Random Davis suggested. (Plus, I already told you what the problem is - you replaced the numbers with strings, but then compare those strings to numbers...)

Comment: @user17086391 we can only help you if you actually read and follow our advice. Or at least try. If you get stuck you can always explain what you're stuck on.

Comment: Hi, as commented, you shouldn't name a variable as "bool" because it is reserved for Python. Maybe you can name it a descriptive way such as "computer_wins". Also as a concise way of choosing from a list randomly, you can: computer = random.choice(["rock", "paper", "scissors"])

Comment: Thanks a lot to all of you great friends I finally found my error with 'comparing string to integer' which is suggested by CherryDT and also founded what that I try to found guess from given string thanks a lot ihpar and all of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have first assigned numbers to the variables `computer` and `player`. After that you change it to a string. but you looking for a number in the `def game(computer,player)` function.

I didn't change your variable name or code structure. read all comments under your question and change the code as you wish.

```
import random
random_element = random.randrange(1,4)
computer = random_element
print("Computer have choosen their, Now it's your turn.")
player = int(input("Plyer's Turn: Enter (1) to choose Stone, (2) for Paper, and (3) for Scissor:\n"))
if player == 1:
    player = 'Stone'
if player == 2:
    player = 'Paper'
if player == 3:
    player = 'Scissor'
if computer == 1:
    computer = 'Stone'
if computer == 2:
    computer = 'Paper'
if computer == 3:
    computer = 'Scissor'
def game(computer,player):
    
    bool = 1
    if computer == player:
        bool = None
    elif  computer == 'Stone':
        if player == 'Paper':
           bool = True
        if player == 'Scissor':
            bool = False
    elif computer == 'Paper':
        if player == 'Scissor':
            bool = True
        if player == 'Stone':
            bool = False
    elif computer == 'Scissor':
        if player == 'Stone':
            bool =  True  
        if player == 'Paper':
            bool = False      
    return bool

if player == 1:
    player = 'Stone'
if player == 2:
    player = 'Paper'
if player == 3:
    player = 'Scissor'    
print(computer)

answer = game(computer,player)

if answer == True:
    print(f"Computer chosen: {computer} \nand You chosen: {player} \nSo, You Won the Game.")

if answer == False:
    print(f"Computer chosen: {computer}\nand You chosen: {player}\nSo, You loose the Game.")

if answer == None:    
    print(f"Computer was chosen: {computer}\nand you choose: {player}\nIt is a Tie..")
```